# Numbers to Dates in SQL Where Statement

Tags: sql, date, format, where-clause

I have a table with 2 columns, EffectiveBeginDate and EffectiveEndDate. However, they're in a number YYYYMMDD format so for example:

Agent     | EffectiveBeginDate | EffectiveEndDate

John Doe  | 20080922           | 20080924

Mark Smith| 20100922           | 20110226

etc. etc.

I need to do 2 things. First, I need to have a formula to change the EffectiveBegin/End dates to an actual date format in my Select statement.

More importantly, I need to be able to query this column in my where statement as if they were acutal dates b/c the where clause is going to be something like:

Where EffectiveStartDate between '01/01/2010' and '01/31/2010'

Thoughts?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio

Answer (score 0):

In SQL SERVER it is sufficient to perform `CONVERT(DATETIME, dateTimeField)` when dateTimeField is in the format "yyyymmdd".

Update:

For numeric dates, use this:
`CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(char(8),dateTimeField) )`

Comment: Thanks. When I said they were in the YYYYMMDD format, I meant that they were numerically in that format, not actual dates. So if I were to do a Convert(datetime, datetimefield), I get an arithmetic overflow error- Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.